# How to have a variable in XPATH in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have an XML like this , I want to make sure that every parameterDef ref of a particular preDefinedRecipe should be a subset of parameterDef of its corecponding recipeStructureDef.

eg) All paramenets Of 'BREAD' FROM predefinedrecipes should belong the recipeStructureDef 'BREAD'

```
  <recipeConfig>
    <recipeStructures> <!-- recipe template/ recipeStructureTypes-->

        <recipeStructureDef mnemonic="BREAD" title="Recipe.Bread"/>
        <parametersTab>
                <parameterTabDef title="Recipe.Bread.Main">
                    <parameterGroup title="group1">
                            <parameterDef mnemonic="SUGAR_QTY"/>
                            <parameterDef mnemonic="SALT_QTY"/ >
                    </parameterGroup>   
                </parameterTabDef>
        </parametersTab>

        <recipeStructureDef mnemonic="CAKE" title="Recipe.Bread"/> 
        .....
         <recipeStructureDef mnemonic="PANCAKE" title="Recipe.Bread"/> 
        .....
     </recipeStructures>


     <preDefinedRecipes>
        <preDefinedRecipe type="BREAD" name="sweet bread"  ordinal="1" writerLevel="Service">
        <parameterDef ref="SUGAR_QTY" value="3" />
                <parameterDef ref="SALT_QTY" value="3" />
                <parameterDef ref="OIL_QTY" value="1" /> 

        </preDefinedRecipe>
      </preDefinedRecipes>
</recipeConfig>
```

I have the following code whichs all parmams belong to the params in recipeStructures but i want to, verify it each preDefinedRecipe type ="" against recipeStructureDef mnemonic=" "

I assume the way is to add variable in XPATH but not sure how to proceed.

```
  <xs:key name="paramKey">
    <xs:selector xpath="./recipeStructures/recipeStructureDef/parametersTab/parameterTabDef/parameterGroup/parameterDef" />
    <xs:field xpath="@mnemonic" />
    </xs:key>
    <xs:keyref name="paramKeyRef" refer="paramKey">
      <xs:selector xpath="./preDefinedRecipes/preDefinedRecipe/parameterDef"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@ref"/>
    </xs:keyref>
   </xs:element>
```

Any guidance will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

The XPath subset defined for use in xs:key / xs:keyref does not allow use of variables.

The same is true for the (larger) XPath subset allowed in XSD 1.1 for assertions and the like. I don't fully understand your requirements, but it looks to me as if an XSD 1.1 assertion will do the job, even without variables.

Comment: the requirement is
SUGAR_QTY, SALT_QTY,OIL_QTY under <preDefinedRecipe type="BREAD"> should always be under the <parameterDef mnemonic> of the particular <recipeStructureDef mnemonic="BREAD"> .
In this case OIL_QTY-> BREAD in "preDefinedRecipe"is not a parameter of  corresponding  <recipeStructureDef mnemonic="BREAD"> so it should pop up error.

Comment: I think you've defined the key and keyref the wrong way round. I can't see why you think that variables would be useful.